# Hashing vertices of a Graph in C

Tags: arrays, c, hash, hashtable

Relative beginner in `C` here so go easy on me! Consider the following structures and types:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef u32 color;
typedef struct Vertice* vertice; // Puntero al Vertice
typedef struct Lado* lado;       // Puntero al Lado
typedef struct GrafoSt* Grafo;

struct GrafoSt {
    u32 n;              // Numero de vertices del grafo
    u32 m;              // Numero de lados del grafo
    u32 delta;          // Max de grados
    u32 sigma;          // Min de grados
    vertice* _vertices; // Arreglo de punteros a Vertice
    lado* _lados;       // Max m*2
};

struct Vertice {
    u32 nombre; // Nombre del vertice
    u32 grado;  // Numero de vecinos
    color color_;
    // Modificar
    u32* Vecinos; // Puntero al indice del primer vecino
};

struct Lado {
    u32 x;
    u32 y;
};
```

As you can see, `_vertices` is an array of pointers to `Vertice`. On initialization, this array is set to size `Grafo -> n`, the number of vertices in the graph.

I'm dealing with very large graph structures (potentially millions of vertices, and consequently even more edges). Thus, efficiency becomes a serious issue. I've been advised to use hashing to store each pointer to `Vertice` in the `_vertices` array. The general idea of the hashing function would be to store a `Vertice` of `nombre = x` in `(Grapho -> _vertices)[my_hash_function(x)]`.

I'm new to the concept of hashing and have found a few issues. I found in StackOverflow the following hash function:

```
u32 Hashv(u32 x) {
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
    x = (x >> 16) ^ x;
    return (x);
}
```

which reportedly is good. However, the range of this function is `u32`; in other words, it is not restricted to `[0, (Graph -> n) - 1]` the possible index values of the `_vertices` array. My workaround was to use `mod`; this is, to store each each `Vertice` with `nombre = x` in `(Graph -> _vertices)[Hashv(x) % Graph -> n]`. This generated a whole of collisions, which I resolved using linear probing. However, in very large graphs, the great number of collisions makes the implementation suboptimal.

Is the idea of hashing verteces a good approach indeed? If so, how could it be improved in this implementation?

---

EDIT: The purpose of working with graphs is to design and test graph coloring algorithms. This makes it important to have an efficient access to the neighbors (`Vecinos`) of a gien vertex. For example, in a Greedy coloring algorithm, to color a vertex `x` I'll need to know the color of its neighbors.

The way I'm loading the graphs and initializing the struct is not really important I think so I'll skip that. I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: a) I don't know which OS you are using, but there are probably hashing functions available (e.g. `man hcreate`).  b) It might be good to give a higher level overview of what you are going to do with your graph so that the readers can suggest a proper storage method.   There are many different ways to organize the data (various trees, hash, array+hash, etc.), and it very much depends on what you're going to be doing with it.

Comment: I edited providing a few details, thanks.

Comment: Regarding `typedef struct Vertice* vertice`: I discourage you from using `typedef` with every struct, but I *strongly recommend* not hiding a pointer behind a typedef.

Comment: Duly noted @JonathonReinhart, I appreciate that kind of feedback. As I said, I'm fairly new to C.

Comment: If your code works but you're not sure your design is good, you might want to ask on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: With a hash map you should expect to get a lot of collisions. You need to have many more hash table positions than values to put in them, typically 2x is okay. Then, only a minority of inserts will be collisions, probably. You can then insert at (Graph -> _vertices)[Hashv(x) % (2*Graph -> n)].

Comment: @SimonGoater Aha! This is excellent to know because I thought about this idea but wasn't sure on how to pick the correct "expansion" (by expansion, I mean a positive k s.t. (G -> n) + k is the new size of the hash table). Does duplicating the number of positions (using k = n, in my terminology) come just from standard practice? Or is there a reason such value is preferred?

Comment: By the way, one must keep in mind that I'm usually leading with millions of vertices... Thus, duplicating the hash table with n > 1.000.000 may be very costly in terms of memory.

Comment: It's a trade-off. You can go smaller, e.g. 3/2x, but it quickly starts to increase the number of collisions, and hence performance. With random inserts, I think you get about 3 in 8 inserts colliding somewhere around 3/2x. There's generally not much point going much bigger than 2x. I find 2x is a happy medium if you can afford the space.